# jQuery Does Not Run on WooCommerce form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I've been banging my head against the wall on this,
My jQuery code runs perfect in CodePen, the WP site in console also runs jQuery however I simply can not get it to run on the actual WooCommerce My Account Billing Address page no matter what.

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Your code in here
    $('#billing_test').on('change', function () {
        myFunc();
    })
    function myFunc() {
        // your function code
        var complex_name = $('#billing_test').val();

        var suburb = $('#billing_suburb').val();

        if (complex_name == 'mr') {
            alert('works');
            $("#billing_suburb").val('LDM');
            $('#billing_postcode').val('5000');
        }
    }
})
```

I've tried adding via Code Snippets to no luck so tried a script file with the following code:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

But still nothing. Any and all help will be really grateful as I've attempted everything I could but still nothing.

I have also tried replacing the $ with jQuery, tried the $.noConflict() as well.

Added script manually and it is in the inspect:

Comment: Is your file loading in the frontend? Definitely you need to declare the $ as being an alias for jQuery

Comment: Did find the issue of it being read from parent directory not child theme, any idea how to get it to read from child? Tried theme-root and then the name of the child but still adds that onto the main theme folder name

Answer (score 0):

The file was reading from parent theme directory not the child theme directory thus the issue of it not being read.